# Numpy array indexing and/or addition seems slow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was playing around with benchmarking numpy arrays because I was getting slower than expected results when I tried to replace python arrays with numpy arrays in a script.

I know I'm missing something, and I was hoping someone could clear up my ignorance.

I created two functions and timed them

```
NUM_ITERATIONS = 1000

def np_array_addition():
    np_array = np.array([1, 2])
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        np_array[0] += x
        np_array[1] += x


def py_array_addition():
    py_array = [1, 2]
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        py_array[0] += x
        py_array[1] += x
```

Results:

```
np_array_addition: 2.556 seconds
py_array_addition: 0.204 seconds
```

What gives? What's causing the massive slowdown? I figured that if I was using statically sized arrays numpy would be at least the same speed.

Thanks!

## **Update:**

It kept bothering me that numpy array access was slow, and I figured "Hey, they're just arrays in memory right? Cython should solve this!"

And it did. Here's my revised benchmark

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np    

ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t    


NUM_ITERATIONS = 200000
def np_array_assignment():
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] np_array = np.array([1, 2])
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        np_array[0] += 1
        np_array[1] += 1    


def py_array_assignment():
    py_array = [1, 2]
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        py_array[0] += 1
        py_array[1] += 1
```

I redefined the `np_array` to `cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1]`

```
print(timeit(py_array_assignment, number=3))
# 0.03459
print(timeit(np_array_assignment, number=3))
# 0.00755
```

That's with the python function also being optimized by cython. The timing for the python function in pure python is

```
print(timeit(py_array_assignment, number=3))
# 0.12510
```

A 17x speedup. Sure it's a silly example, but I thought it was educational.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I'd say it's the extra work from changing context between C and Python back and forth what is killing the performance here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not (just) addition which is slow, it is element access overhead, see for example:

```
def np_array_assignment():
    np_array = np.array([1, 2])
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        np_array[0] = 1
        np_array[1] = 1


def py_array_assignment():
    py_array = [1, 2]
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        py_array[0] = 1
        py_array[1] = 1

timeit np_array_assignment()
10000 loops, best of 3: 178 us per loop

timeit py_array_assignment()
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.5 us per loop
```

Numpy is fast with operating on vectors (matrices), when performed on the whole structure at once. Such single element-by-element operations are slow.

Use numpy functions to avoid looping, making operations on the whole array at once, i.e.:

```
def np_array_addition_good():
    np_array = np.array([1, 2])
    np_array += np.sum(np.arange(NUM_ITERATIONS))
```

The results comparing your functions with the one above are pretty revealing:

```
timeit np_array_addition()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop

timeit py_array_addition()
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 us per loop

timeit np_array_addition_good()
100000 loops, best of 3: 11 us per loop
```

But actually, you can do as good with pure python if you collapse the loops:

```
def py_array_addition_good():
        py_array = [1, 2]
        rangesum = sum(range(NUM_ITERATIONS))
        py_array = [x + rangesum for x in py_array]

timeit py_array_addition_good()
100000 loops, best of 3: 11 us per loop
```

All in all, with such simple operations there is really no improvement in using numpy. Optimized code in pure python works just as good.

---

There were a lot of questions about it and I suggest looking at some good answers there:

[How do I maximize efficiency with numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399361/how-do-i-maximize-efficiency-with-numpy-arrays)

[numpy float: 10x slower than builtin in arithmetic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956783/numpy-float-10x-slower-than-builtin-in-arithmetic-operations?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

You're not actually using numpy's vectorized array addition if you do the loop in python; there's also the access overhead mentioned by @shashkello.

I took the liberty of increasing the array size a tad, and also adding a vectorized version of the addition:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

NUM_ITERATIONS = 1000

def np_array_addition():
    np_array = np.array(xrange(1000))
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        for i in xrange(len(np_array)):
            np_array[i] += x

def np_array_addition2():
    np_array = np.array(xrange(1000))
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        np_array += x

def py_array_addition():
    py_array = range(1000)
    for x in xrange(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        for i in xrange(len(py_array)):
            py_array[i] += x

print timeit(np_array_addition, number=3)  # 4.216162
print timeit(np_array_addition2, number=3) # 0.117681
print timeit(py_array_addition, number=3)  # 0.439957
```

As you can see, the vectorized numpy version wins pretty handily. The gap will just get larger as array sizes and/or iterations increase.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So the vector addition shines through more with larger arrays

Comment: You should remove the construction from the array loops, or use the numpy construction functions...